# Different functions in the same class sharing memory of local variables?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, memory-management

I ran into this absurd situation. I am trying to read data from a file. And depending on the kind of tag, it will read a __uint16_t or __uint32_t. So I have two functions in the same class which are called upon as needed.

```
void myclass::readL16()
{
    char tmp[65] = {'\0'};
    __uint16_t len;
    myfile.read(tmp, sizeof(len));
    memcpy(&len, &tmp[0], sizeof(len));
    myfile.read(tmp, len);
    printf ("%.*s", len, tmp);
}

void myclass::readL32()
{
    char tmp[65] = {'\0'};
    __uint32_t len;
    myfile.read(tmp, sizeof(len));
    memcpy(&len, &tmp[0], sizeof(len));
    myfile.read(tmp, len);
    printf ("%.*s", len, tmp);
}
```

This part works just fine.

But if I declare tmp[] to different sizes: e.g.

```
void myclass::readL16()
{
    char tmp[16] = {'\0'};
    ...
}

void myclass::readL32()
{
    char tmp[32] = {'\0'};
    ...
}
```

I run into abort trap 6 error, when I run the program. Why would this happen. Isn't tmp suppose to be local to the respective function?

Comment: That second `myfile.read(tmp, len);` is probably what's doing you in. Print out `len` before the second read to see how many bytes you'll try to read.

Comment: Is the stream  still good after the first read?

Comment: Your code looks fine so the file may be the cause. As *AndyG* said you should print out `len` before reading.

Comment: Although, I still can not find out what was wrong, a clean Make does the job. And now both the functions are behaving.